# Github action error when triggering a databricks notebook using Azure AD auth

Tags: github-actions, azure-databricks, cicd

I'm following the software best practice guidelines as described in this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/best-practices).

I'm currently stuck at the Step 6 where I'm trying to use a github actions workflow to trigger the unit tests on databricks. The documentation talks about using a Access token but also  suggests to use Azure AD/Entra ID instead.

I got the github workflow running successfully using a access token and attempted to update it to use Azure AD instead. I followed the steps given [HERE](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-databricks-notebook#azure).

First I created an app registration with a secret and gave it contributor access to my workspace. I then added the SPN within my workspace and gave it the "Can manage run" permissions for the specific Databricks job. The github action workflow is as follows.

```
name: Run pre-merge Databricks tests

on:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  # Replace this value with your workspace instance name.
  DATABRICKS_HOST: https://adb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azuredatabricks.net

jobs:
  unit-test-notebook:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15

    steps:
      - name: Generate AAD Token
        run: |
          echo "DATABRICKS_TOKEN1=$(curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
          https://login.microsoftonline.com/${{ secrets.AZURE_SP_TENANT_ID }}/oauth2/v2.0/token \
          -d 'client_id=${{ secrets.AZURE_SP_APPLICATION_ID }}' \
          -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
          -d 'scope=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default' \
          -d 'client_secret=${{ secrets.AZURE_SP_CLIENT_SECRET }}' |  jq -r  '.access_token')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run test notebook
        uses: databricks/run-notebook@main
        with:
          databricks-token: $DATABRICKS_TOKEN1
          local-notebook-path: notebooks/run_unit_tests.py
          existing-cluster-id: 1005-025142-oylnzzyy
          git-commit: "${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}"

          # Grant all users view permission on the notebook's results, so that they can
          # see the result of the notebook, if they have related access permissions.
          access-control-list-json: >
            [
              {
                "group_name": "users",
                "permission_level": "CAN_VIEW"
              }
            ]
          run-name: "EDA transforms helper module unit tests"
```

When I run this, the github action fails with the following error.

```
Error: {"error_code":"PERMISSION_DENIED","message":"*** does not have View permissions on 83958068369529. Please contact the owner or an administrator for access."}
```

I am not able to find any information on this error and I can't tell what 83958068369529 relates to.

To dig a bit more, I tried firing the run-now Databricks job API via Postman after getting the bearer token from Azure AD using the AD credentials and that also worked fine. This tells me that the permissions on the SPN are correct and that there may be some problem with the Databricks github action itself.

If I look at this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-github.html), it says that the feature is in public preview. I wanted to reach out to the community to check if anyone else has faced the similar issue or whether this is a documented issue with the beta version of this feature.